# c++ invoke function call without the dot or this pointer operator

Tags: c++

I have a c++ question, please see the code below:

```
ArbitraryIterator *iter = (ArbitraryIterator *) state->iter;

ArbitraryCollection_Entry *result;

result = (ArbitraryCollection_Entry *) (*iter)();
```

My question is at the very end of this code block. I'm not sure what the last portion "(*iter)()" is doing. It's a function call but I'm not sure what it's calling? Is this another way to invoke the constructor? I know this may be a more general question and not so specific to how it's being implement in the above code sample. Any help or clarification on this would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What is `state` ? Show its declaration.

Comment: Making a wild guess I think that `iter` is a pointer to a functor (i.e., a pointer to a function object)

Comment: I cannot say more without knowing what ArbitraryIterator is, but it seems that it would implement an `operator()()` that returns some pointer type in its definition. This is what gets called in the last line.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka What else then? A pointer to `ArbitraryIterator` gets dereferenced, and then we invoke the dereferenced object's `operator()`. According to [this list of precedences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the call happens before the cast - therefore, we cast the value returned by `ArbitraryIterator::operator()`, then cast it to `ArbitraryCollection_Entry*`, and assign it to `result`.

Comment: @MoreAxes Sorry I misread the code you are right

Comment: This seems most likely to me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bff949f277124d7, though all the code is insane and poorly named at best.

Answer (score 3):

```
(*iter)();
```

This is 2 actions :

- Dereferencing `iter` (calling it's `operator*`)
- Calling the `operator()` on the result of the previous operation, without parameters

Your iterator iterates over a collection of callable objects, an example of such a type would be:

```
std::vector<std::function<void*()>>::iterator
```

Comment: Perhaps he meant to write `(void*)`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The code written above is exactly how it appears (with the exception of the actual class  names), so it's not missing a (void*) as More Axes suggest.

Just to be clear, so you're saying that this last portion of code (*iter)() is actually calling the function that's dereferenced by iter? I'm not sure what function this would be.

More specifically, What do you mean by it's "Calling the operator()"?

Comment: @user3780054 He probably suggested that before my edit ;)
The thing that is dereferenced is the iterator itself, the result of that action (the dereferencing) is a function, which is then called without parameters :)

Comment: Thanks Drax.

Just curious, aside from this being an iterator for callable objects, can you think of anything else or are you pretty firm on that assessment?

Comment: @user3780054 I can't think of anything else that could be.